# How to apply a bvh animation to a Cal3D model?

Tags: animation, 3d, skeletal-mesh

I'd like to use a [bvh](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/graphics/Courses/cs-838-1999/Jeff/BVH.html)̉ animation on a [Cal3D](https://mp3butcher.github.io/Cal3D/) model.  At first glance it seems like it ought to be easy:  A bvh file specifies a rotation at each of a hierarchy of joints, and a Ca3D model contains rotations at a hierarchy of joints.  The problem is that I'd like to use bvh files created by other programs, not just those I create, and there is no standard for the neutral pose used in the HIERARCHY part of the bvh file.  Sometimes it's more or less a standard T pose, but sometimes it's nothing like a pose that an actual human could assume.

I could compute the joint positions implied by the bvh data, and find the simplest rotations that would move my model's joints into those positions relative to each other.  But then it seems like I'd be throwing away data, since there isn't a unique rotation that will move a vector to a given direction.